# How to quickly traverse bi-directional nodes without repetition?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I want to optimize a bidirectional node traversal algorithm.

Because the node is bidirectional, it may cause an infinite loop. The current algorithm uses memory records.
However, memory writing will be slower and not friendly to multi-threading.

[image: Maybe I can't express myself well, so I drew a schematic diagram]

So I hope I can remove the memory write operation.
And the insertion and deletion of nodes is equal to O(1).

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: The generic way this is described sounds like a general programming problem that might fit better on StackOverflow. Can you explain more of the context of what this traversal algorithm is doing in your game feature, and include code for a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example?

Comment: @DMGregory  This algorithm is used in the constraint system of physical objects. Use this algorithm to traverse all objects in the entire joint system and then calculate the total momentum

Comment: So the topology is not necessarily a list but could be an arbitrary graph with branching or cycles? Please edit your question to contain the requested code sample.

Comment: @DMGregory Maybe I can't express it well, so I drew a diagram

Comment: Have you considered storing your nodes and constraints in arrays, then just iterating the arrays in order, rather than by following directed links between items? This makes it trivial to avoid repeats, and you can assign each thread a non-overlapping block of array indices it owns for a minimum of thread communication/coordination.

Comment: @DMGregory  I have tried using the "sequential impulse" algorithm to do the calculations. But the effect is not good and the running speed is very slow. especially when an object and an object have multiple constraint points.

Comment: I think you might get better answers if you edit your question to ask "How to optimize calculation of sequential impulse" showing your strategy for calculating it so far and your profiling results showing where the bottlenecks are. That kind of specificity will help tailor answers better to your use case than asking a generic question about iterating graphs, and might even permit higher-level algorithmic optimizations or approximations.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to remove the memory writing in this case. However if you provide how you currently use the memory we might be able to suggest faster and more muli-threading friendly ways than your current solution